# Paypal NVP : SetExpressCheckout : Order Total is missing

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-nvp

I have a problem with SetExpressCheckout paypal nvp . I'm getting the following error

`TIMESTAMP=2014%2d09%2d12T04%3a46%3a48Z&CORRELATIONID=bac06e6e9473d&ACK=Failure&VERSION=112%2e0&BUILD=127
86467&L_ERRORCODE0=10400&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Transaction%20refused%20because%20of%20an%20invalid%20argument%2e%20See%20additional%20error%20messages%20for%20details%2e&L_LONGMESSAGE0=Order%20total%20is%20missing%2e&L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error`

I have passed the following variables for setexpresscheckout,

`&RETURNURL=xxx&CANCELURL=yyy&ALLOWNOTE=1&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=Nokia presents the Lumia a feature-rich mid-range smartphone&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0=xROwRr6F&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=50&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=1&LOGOIMG=mmm&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT=10&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT=0&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=50&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=60&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD`

But error says `"order total is missing"`.. is all passed variables are correct??

Please help!

Comment: Try formatting your amount values with 2 decimal places and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue, because of all item amounts, i have given urlencode and for returnURL & cancelURL, its decoded before passing to paypal server. Now i removed all urlencode from item amounts and that solved the problem.

Thanks!